# Excel.application object variable needed before every Excel function when coding in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have some code in access which open an .htm file, save it as .xlsx then manipulate the data a bit and then import into a table in Access. I use to just use

```
Dim XLapp as Excel.Application
Set XLapp = New Excel.Application
```

then i can do all the manipulation in Excel without putting XLapp in front of every command. But the problem with this is that i create a new Excel instance everytime I run the code and encounter the “Method 'worksheets' of object '_global' failed” error on every other run" (someone already mentioned this problem). So i use

```
Public Function GetExcelObject() As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim xlo As Object
    ' Try to get running instance of Excel
    Set xlo = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If xlo Is Nothing Then

        Set xlo = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Set GetExcelObject = xlo
End Function
```

to just create one Excel instance. But now my code become something like this

```
'delete columns that will not be used

ws.Range("F:J,S:V").Select
XLapp.Selection.Delete
XLapp.Range("A1").Select
XLapp.Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
XLapp.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
XLapp.Selection.Value = "Server"
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ColumnNum = XLapp.ActiveCell.Column
XLapp.Range(XLapp.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), XLapp.Cells(lastrow, ColumnNum)).Select
XLapp.Selection.Value = UCase(Right(ws.Name, (Len(ws.Name) - InStr(1, ws.Name, "_"))))
XLapp.Range("B1").Select
XLapp.Selection.Value = "Client_Name"
XLapp.Columns("J:J").Select
XLapp.Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

i have to put XLapp in front of every single command.

The entire code is as the following

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


    Public fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, ofile, queue As Collection
    Public sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Public currentRowValue As String
    Public objExcelAddwb As Object
    Public wb As Excel.Workbook
    Public ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Public lastrow As Long
    Public ColumnNum As Long
    Public SQL As String
    Public Updated_SQL As String
    Public CurrentDB As Database
    Public StatusVar As Variant
    Public XLapp As Excel.Application





Private Sub btn_Import_Report_Click()
    'Set objXLapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set XLapp = GetExcelObject()


    'Set wb = objXLapp.Workbooks.Add

    'Set XLapp = Excel.Application
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection


    'objXLapp.Visible = False


    'Set obExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder(CurrentProject.Path & "\Process_Report") 'obviously replace

    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
        '...insert any folder processing code here...
    For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue

        Next oSubfolder

        For Each ofile In oFolder.Files

        StatusVar = SysCmd(4, "Processing " & ofile)

        If InStrRev(ofile, "Account") > 0 Then

        Import_Accounts_Report fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, ofile, queue, wb, ws, XLapp, lastrow, ColumnNum

        ElseIf InStrRev(ofile, "Closed") > 0 Then

        Import_Closed_Trade_Report fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, ofile, queue, wb, ws, XLapp, lastrow, ColumnNum

        ElseIf InStrRev(ofile, "Raw") > 0 Then

        Import_Raw_Report fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, ofile, queue, wb, ws, XLapp, lastrow, ColumnNum

        ElseIf InStrRev(ofile, "History") > 0 Then

        Import_History_Report fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, ofile, queue, wb, ws, XLapp, lastrow, ColumnNum

        ElseIf InStrRev(ofile, "Orders") > 0 Then

        Import_Orders_Report fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, ofile, queue, wb, ws, XLapp, lastrow, ColumnNum

        ElseIf InStrRev(ofile, "Summary") > 0 Then

        Import_Position_Summary_Report fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, ofile, queue, wb, ws, XLapp, lastrow, ColumnNum

        End If

        Next

        Loop

    StatusVar = SysCmd(5)




    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing

    'Set Selection = Nothing

    Set ofile = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set queue = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oSubfolder = Nothing
    'XLapp.Quit
    Set XLapp = Nothing


Form_Main_Menu.Visible = True



MsgBox ("All Reports Imported")



End Sub
```

then in another import module:

```
Sub Import_Accounts_Report(fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, ofile, queue As Collection, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet, XLapp As Excel.Application, lastrow As Long, ColumnNum As Long)


        Set wb = XLapp.Workbooks.Open(ofile)

        XLapp.DisplayAlerts = False

        wb.SaveAs FileName:=CurrentProject.Path & "\Ready_To_Import\" & Left(wb.Name, Len(wb.Name) - 4), FileFormat:=51

        XLapp.DisplayAlerts = True

        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

        'delete previous accounts report data

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False

        If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "Msysobjects", "Name='tbl_Accounts_Report'")) Then


        SQL = "DELETE tbl_Accounts_Report.Server" & _
            " FROM tbl_Accounts_Report" & _
            " WHERE (((tbl_Accounts_Report.Server)='Replace'))"

        Updated_SQL = Replace(SQL, "Replace", Right(ws.Name, (Len(ws.Name) - InStr(1, ws.Name, "_"))))

        DoCmd.RunSQL Updated_SQL

        Else

        CurrentDB.Execute "Create Table Accounts_Report"

        End If

        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        'delete the first row
        ws.Activate
        ws.Range("1:1").Select
        XLapp.Selection.Delete

        'Remove space in numbers

        XLapp.DisplayAlerts = False

        XLapp.Columns("Q:R").Select
        XLapp.Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        XLapp.DisplayAlerts = True

        'delete columns that will not be used

        ws.Range("F:J,S:V").Select
        XLapp.Selection.Delete
        XLapp.Range("A1").Select
        XLapp.Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
        XLapp.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        XLapp.Selection.Value = "Server"
        lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ColumnNum = XLapp.ActiveCell.Column
        XLapp.Range(XLapp.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), XLapp.Cells(lastrow, ColumnNum)).Select
        XLapp.Selection.Value = UCase(Right(ws.Name, (Len(ws.Name) - InStr(1, ws.Name, "_"))))
        XLapp.Range("B1").Select
        XLapp.Selection.Value = "Client_Name"
        XLapp.Columns("J:J").Select
        XLapp.Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

        'unmerge the spreadsheet

        XLapp.Columns("I:I").Select
        XLapp.Selection.UnMerge
        With Selection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With

        'separate date and time and format date and time
        XLapp.DisplayAlerts = False

        Columns("I:I").Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("I1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 5), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        XLapp.DisplayAlerts = True

        Columns("I:I").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        Columns("J:J").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"

        Range("I1").Select
        Selection.Value = "Reg_Date"
        Range("J1").Select
        Selection.Value = "Reg_Time"

        'import to the DB

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "tbl_Accounts_Report", CurrentProject.Path & "\Ready_To_Import\" & wb.Name, True
        XLapp.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Close
        XLapp.DisplayAlerts = True


        Set ws = Nothing
        Set wb = Nothing
        XLapp.Quit
        Set XLapp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Somebody please help.

Thanks

Comment: A few suggestions: avoid using select. Instead of `ws.Range("F:J,S:V").Select` and then `XLapp.Selection.Delete`, just say: `XLapp.ws.Range("F:J,S:V").Delete`. Also, use a with statement, so you don't need to precede each line with `XLapp`. Learn about them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

Comment: Your solution is not going to change the requirement to reference xlApp. Where is rest of your code that sets the object?

Comment: XLapp.Selection.UnMerge
        With Selection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With                                                                                         but VBA says error object not set. when i hover over selection, selection=nothing

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your `XLapp` block of code does not work as there is no *.Range*, *.Selection*, *.ActiveCell*, etc. methods to the *Excel.Application* object. These are Excel worksheet level methods. So instead of `XLapp.Range("A1").Select`, the correct reference would be: `XLwks.Range("A1").Select`.

Interestingly enough, you already set the workbook and worksheet objects:

```
Set wb = XLapp.Workbooks.Open(ofile)
...
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
```

Therefore, continue using the worksheet object, `ws` not `XLapp`. And to avoid repetitious prefixing of `ws.`, consider using the `With` clause. Also, you can remove many of your *Selects*:

```
    XLapp.DisplayAlerts = True

    'delete columns that will not be used
    With ws
        .Range("F:J,S:V").Select
        XLapp.Selection.Delete
        .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) = "Server"
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ColumnNum = .ActiveCell.Column
        .Range(.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), .Cells(lastrow, ColumnNum)) _
            = UCase(Right(.Name, (Len(.Name) - InStr(1, .Name, "_"))))
        .Range("B1") = "Client_Name"
        .Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

        'unmerge the spreadsheet

        .Columns("I:I").UnMerge
    End With
```

Also, be sure all Excel constants are properly declared as they are not known in the MS Access object library which the debugger will remind you:

```
Const xlToRight = -4161
Const xlUp = -4162
```

Comment: Thans for your answer. I thin I have found pinpointed the problem. When there is no instance of Excel running, the code works fine without adding XLapp, but if there is an instance of Excel already running, I will have problem.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but have your Access subroutine manage the child process, here being Excel, including opening/running operations/closing, which you have all in place but simply used the wrong object referencing.

Comment: I tried the with statement, error on the line "Selection.Delete", Method or Data member not found.

Comment: For certain *Selection* items, you do need `XLApp` object as that is akin to users selecting regions on worksheet, a process at app level.

Comment: Looking closer, you use many `Selects` on cell values where you can assign values directly: `.Range("B1") = "Client_Name"`.